# How to show direct my application Location settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

Now I'm using this code for showing location settings. But it's a move to the settings screen. I need to show my application location settings options. And I mentioned URL in project TARGET. Please check the

I was tried more but until I didn't get any proper result

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)

NSString* url = SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"10.0") ? @"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES" : @"App-prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION_SERVICES";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

I want to move to direct my application Location setting screen. But it is going to setting screen only.

Please check this image I mentioned pref in project targect :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method which you are trying is deprecated since iOS 8.0. You have to use `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` method which directly open App Settings page.

Comment: Thank you it is working.